# Create a listview with sides like older email android app

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create a listview like older gmail app. See the screenshot:

[image]

I tried putting an empty view like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/color_highlight"
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:minHeight="48dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/color_highlight"
    android:text="Mudit Agarwal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#242424"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/name"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:text="9933445566"
    android:textColor="#777777"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/contact" />
```

but this is not taking full height of the view. Please suggest.

Comment: can you post your layout for item? require to set it with other. And can you tell me what do you want coz i can't understand by empty view. Please elaborate by some arrow in pic.

Comment: @ChintanRathod, i have added full layout. Please have a look.

Comment: I posted my answer. please have a look.

Comment: isn't your problem get solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I changed is

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/number"
```

to your `color_highlight` TextView. and instead of `margin`, I put `padding` like below in `number` TextView.

```
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

just put following layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/color_highlight"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/number"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/color_highlight"
        android:text="Mudit Agarwal"
        android:textColor="#242424"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/name"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="9933445566"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/contact" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Glad to help my friend.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try putting **`android:layout_height="0dip"`** instead of **`android:layout_height="match_parent"`**.

Comment: i am using a relative layout in the view..so putting height as 0dp wont work.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention it. One thing is, when I want different elements in a ListView's item, I generally put those elements into a FrameLayout. It worked for me till now!